# What is the correct type of relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database, eloquent

I have system that logs projects to project managers,

> 1 Project Can Have Multiple Project Managers

The project managers are essentially just system users, maybe I am having a brain fart but I am struggling to work out the correct relationship to get the data out I need, what I am wanting to is get the database, the project details and the user details for each project manager.

I envisage it being a 1:n relationship but I cannot seem to get the data I want, I am using eloquent to get my relationships and load the data, here are my models,

**Project.php**

```
public function projectmanager() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function projectmanager() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Project');
}
```

But that does not seems to make sense, in my head it feels like I need my project table, user table, and then a further table that would store and ID, the user id, and the project id.

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction, because I am just confusing myself at the moment

Answer (score 0):

### Case 1.

If *"One Project Can Have Multiple PMs"* and *"One PM Can Have Only One Project"* - you need **One-to-Many** relationship.

**Project.php**

```
public function managers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Manager');
}
```

**Manager.php**

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Project');
}
```

In this case you need 2 tables: one for projects and one for PMs. In PMs table there should be a field like project_id, which is a foreign key pointing to id field in projects table.

### Case 2.

If *"One Project Can Have Multiple PMs"* and *"One PM Can Have Multiple Projects"* - then you need **Many-to-Many** relationship.

**Project.php**

```
public function managers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Manager');
}
```

**Manager.php**

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Project');
}
```

In this case you need 3 tables: projects table, PMs table (with no foreign key in this case) and so called pivot table, which helds corresponding id fields from projects and PMs tables.

More on relationships and models you can learn in:

- [Laravel 4.2 Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)
- [Laravel 5.0 Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)
- [Laravel 6.x Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)
- [Laravel 7.x Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)
- [Laravel 8.x Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

depending on which version you are using.

To create these tables you can use **Migrations**. You can learn more on this in:

- [Laravel 4.2 Migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations)
- [Laravel 5.0 Migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations)
- [Laravel 6.x Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations)
- [Laravel 7.x Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations)
- [Laravel 8.x Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)

depending on which version you are using.